# Selendroid scroll and flick dont work

Tags: java, android, scroll, selendroid

I want to scroll up a spinner while testing my app using Selendroid. I have tried to use the .scroll and .flick methods. While the .scroll works it doesn't update the content of the spinner and the .flick method either it doesn't do anything or the .perform() doesnt work.
Here is the Java code code that i used in both cases:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("spinner"));
    TouchActions scroll = new TouchActions(driver).flick(element, 0, -100, 0);
    flick.perform();
```

OR

```
           WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("spinner"));
           TouchActions scroll = new TouchActions(driver).scroll(selCount,0,-100);
           scroll.perform();
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **NATIVE**, **WEBVIEW** or **WEBVIEW_0** ? Could you paste Selendroid console log? In my opinion searching by xpath is more precise then searching by id, in some cases it's just better and faster. 
And be sure that "element" is ready to use. Maybe you should give some time to driver by using

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, time); 
wait.until(...);
```

full description about this you'll find on selenium home page.
 http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp